# String outputs confusing with +

Tags: java, string

public class Test2 {
    public static void main (String[] args){

```
    System.out.println("3 + 6"); 
    System.out.println(3 + 6); 
    System.out.println(3 + 6 + "buffer"); 
    System.out.println("buffer" + 3 + 6); 
    System.out.println("buffer " + (3 + 6)); 
 }


}
```

the output for

```
 System.out.println(3 + 6 + "buffer");
```

is

> 9 buffer

and 
the output for

```
System.out.println("buffer" + 3 + 6);
```

is

> buffer 36

why the difference? and why

```
System.out.println(3 + 6);
```

output is

> 9

?

Comment: In simple words expression evaluation takes from left to right, check for the opperands of the + operator and behaves accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The arithmetic operator resolves from left to right. And when you do `+` With string it's append as a string.

```
System.out.println(3 + 6 + "buffer");
```

That becomes

```
System.out.println(  9 + "buffer");
```

And when you do

```
System.out.println("buffer" + 3 + 6);
```

that evaluates as

```
 //  "buffer3" + 6
 //  "buffer36"
```

and

```
 System.out.println(3 + 6)
```

There is no string concatenation. So direct integer addition happend.

In case of

```
System.out.println("buffer " + (3 + 6));
```

You added parenthesis to `3+6`. Due to the higher precedence that expression in parenthesis evaluates first. Hence that becomes

```
System.out.println("buffer " + 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

The expressions passed to `println` are evaluated before being passed.

They are evaluated from left to right.

If the first (left) operand in the expression is a String, `+` performs String concatenation, so `"buffer" + 3 + 6` becomes `"buffer3" + 6` which becomes `"buffer36"`.

If the first and second operands are numbers, `+` performs addition, so `3 + 6 + "buffer"` becomes `9 + "buffer"` which becomes `"9buffer"`.

If some of the operands are surrounded by brackets, the operator between them is applied first, so `"buffer " + (3 + 6)` is equivalent to `"buffer " + 9`.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions are evaluating left to right direction.

So `System.out.println(3 + 6 + "buffer");` in this line firstly evaluating sum of integer numbers and `System.out.println("buffer" + 3 + 6);` here is the first type is string and evaluating type conversion according to string type to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you pass is first evaluated starting from left to right. Here in case of 3+6+"buffer" the first two parameters are integer so the + operator adds them and sum is 9 and when it gets the third parameter "buffer" which is a string, it converts the result to string and prints it. Hence you get the string "9buffer" as result.

However in the second case "buffer"+3+6 first parameter is string and second is integer so second param is converted to string first and then + operator concatenates them. Similar is the case when it reaches the third operator it does "buffer"+6 and again concatenates it and hence result becomes "buffer36".

Answer (score 0):

if you are using + sign for String, the java compiler take it as concatenate and automatically call `toString` to other object.

So when you are trying to print `3+6+"stuff"` it means int+int+contate  to String so first it add two number and after that converts it to string and concate it with `"stuff".`
And if you call `"stuff"+3+6` it will print `stuff36`

Answer (score 0):

In the first one (3+6+"buffer") when the program is run java reads your program from left so it takes 3 and 6 as integer and their sum is 9 then it reads a string so it joins it with the string and result is "9buffer".
In the second one ("buffer"+3+6) it reads string first so it joins the other to with it 
and result is buffer36.
In the third one (3+6) it takes them integers because no string is present before them 
so it gives 9.